# how to pass a scala List to NetLogo

Tags: scala, netlogo

I have a Scala list and I am trying to pass it to my NetLogo model:

```
> myscalalist
List(2015-01, 2015-02)
```

I am trying this:

```
App.app.command("set months " + myscalalist)
```

but I get an error at line 47 of my ABM class:

```
Illegal number format at position 54 in 
at org.nlogo.lex.Tokenizer.tokenize(Tokenizer.scala:30)
at org.nlogo.lex.Tokenizer.tokenize(Tokenizer.scala:26)
at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:23)
at org.nlogo.compiler.Compiler$.compileMoreCode(Compiler.scala:34)
at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.org$nlogo$workspace$Evaluator$$invokeCompiler(Evaluator.scala:175)
at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.evaluateCommands(Evaluator.scala:18)
at org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceTraits$Evaluating$class.evaluateCommands(AbstractWorkspaceScala.scala:163)
at org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceScala.evaluateCommands(AbstractWorkspaceScala.scala:19)
at org.nlogo.app.App.command(App.scala:849)
at main.jago.ABM$$anonfun$simulate$1.apply(ABM.scala:47)
```

Is there any recommendation to pass safety a list to NetLogo from a Scala app?

Comment: What is the signature of the command method? What does it expect?

Comment: Good point, I have to check

Comment: looks like it expects a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer will work for most kinds of values, but using the NetLogo-specific APIs instead of general Scala ones will work in more cases:

```
org.nlogo.api.Dump.logoObject(
  org.nlogo.api.LogoList(
    myscalalist.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]]: _*),
  true, false)
```

On your input list, this produces the string:

```
["2015-01" "2015-02"]
```

The typecast is unfortunate, but it's necessary in order for this to work even on Scala types such as e.g. `List[Double]`; normally NetLogo expects values to be subtypes of `AnyRef`.

Comment: then I can assign the logoObject to a net logo variable or should I just read-from-string the result?

Comment: it looks like is not working for a List[Double], but only for a List[String]

Comment: re: logoObject, the result is a string, which is what you need in order to use it with `app.command`. (The method name describes the argument type, not the result type.) re: `List[Double]`, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of NetLogo or its api. But assuming it takes a string and parses it, the error is probably in the way toString works on a scala list

Use `.mkString(", ")` method on your list, this will turn `List(2015-01, 2015-02)` into `"2015-01, 2015-02"`

The string that mkString accepts is the separator,

```
App.app.command("set months " + myscalalist.mkString(", "))
```

Comment: yes, the right answer for net logo is to use .mkString("[", " ", "]") and then read-from-string within net logo code... thanks